# Android Detect Flag Emojis Present

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, emoji

It was my understanding that as of Lollipop (Android 5.0), the flag emojis would be included. I have a Google Nexus device and a Samsung Galaxy Note 4, and the Nexus has the emojis while the Samsung just shows the two letter country code. Is there anyway to detect if the flag emojis are supported so I could just hide the country codes if the emoji flags aren't there?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460528